# Packing integers close together in a vector - can it be done faster?

Tags: c++, c++11, data-structures, bit-manipulation

For the data structure I'm currently making, I need to pack the integers closely together. This means, that if the maximum element in a vector is n, I would use at most lg n bits to represent it. Thus, I treat a vector of integers like a list of bits. My current solution works just fine - but I need to know if I can speed up the unpacking of an integer. That lookup operation is a quite integral part of the search query to my data structure.

```
// uint is an unsigned 32 bit integer (std::uint32_t)
uint
Data::findInt(const std::vector<uint>& input, int size, int pos) {
    pos = pos*size;
    int end = pos+size;
    int firstc = pos/32;
    int secondc = end/32;
    int ipos = pos % 32;
    int jpos = end % 32;

    if(firstc == secondc) {
        uint number = input.at(firstc);
        number = number >> (32 - end);
        number = number & ((1 << size) - 1);
        return number;
    }
    // else
    uint number = input.at(firstc);
    number = number << (jpos);
    number = number & ((1 << size) -1);
    uint number2 = input.at(secondc);
    number2 = number2 >> (32 - jpos);
    number2 = number2 & ((1 << jpos) - 1);

    return number + number2;
}

std::vector<uint>
Data::packBits(const std::vector<uint>& input, int size) {

    std::vector<char> bits = translatetobits(input, size);
    while(bits.size() % 32 != 0) {
        bits.push_back(0);
    }

    std::vector<uint> packedbits;
    for(int i = 0; i < bits.size(); i += 32) {
        uint res = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < 31; ++j) {
            res += (bits.at(i+j));
            res = res << 1;
        }
        res += (bits.at(i+31));
        packedbits.push_back(res);
    }

    // Current lookup requires an empty entry - should be fixed
    packedbits.push_back(0);

    return packedbits;
}
```

I can only fetch one integer at a time and the index of a look-up operation jumps quite arbitrarily around, so I can't batch look-ups together. Does anyone have a good idea for speeding up the look-up?

Comment: Can you avoid the cost of the branch by *always* reading two consecutive elements?

Answer (score 1):

`at` is checked.  Check bounds once, not each interaction with the vector.

Consider using raw pointers instead of vectors for the low level operations.

Your packing is extremely inefficient -- it does memory allocation.  Why in gods name.

You should be using fixed sized data, not generic `uint`s.

You have duplicated code calculating `number`.  Consider eliminating.  The constant `32` in that code is a matter of how the bits where packed -- pack in a different way, save an operation.

You can optimize for branclessness if you want, but that will probably not grant a performance increase (it will grant a worst-case performance increase, but not repeated operations, as branch predictors are pretty solid).  One possibility is to always unpack your data into a 64 bit unsigned type, then shift it away: I think there are ways to do it so that the 2nd lookup just injects zeros, or data that gets masked out, if it isn't needed.